# Node.js Read daily tip from a text document

Tags: node.js, bots, discord

I am currently working on a Discord bot and was wondering if there is a way to get the bot to automatically post a daily tip, which it would read from a text file and display it on the relevant Dicord channel.

I can get it to display the whole file repeatedly (I have been testing it with a 5 second timeout), however, I cannot get it to display the first line only, wait 5 seconds, display the second line only, wait 5 seconds etc.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to convert the text file containing tips into an Array. Let's assume you entered all your tips an array called `dailyTips`. You can use `bot.setInterval(() => {...}, time)` in your `bot.on('ready', () => {...}` event. The bot will execute the command every milli-seconds you specify in time.

```
let dailyTips = ['...', '...', '...'];

bot.on('ready', () => {
  bot.setInterval(() => {
    let toSendChannel = bot.channels.get('id'); // The channel you will send the tip in
    let tip = dailyTips[Math.floor(Math.random() * dailyTips.length)]; // get random tip from the array
    toSendChannel.send(tip);
  }, 86400000); // 1 day = 86400000 ms
});

bot.login(token);
```

I hope I cleared everything out for you.